# Timed stream redirect

Tags: command-line, redirect, console, stream, pipe

How can I do a "timed redirect"?  I have a program which accepts user input from `stdin`, which the user can naturally enter at various paces.  But now I want to have the input read from a file at a certain pace.  I have tried writing a Python script which pauses after every `readline()` and to pipe the input, but that process finishes first before the output is sent to the second program:

`python slowrelease.py my_input_data.txt 10 | some_program`

(The "10" indicates that I want the contents of `my_input_data.txt` streamed over 10 seconds.)

I am working on the Windows command-line, but would be interested to know whether this is possible under Unix as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten to flush the lines that I was writing to `stdout`.  This meant that the Python script was just buffering all the output and then writing it all at once when it finished.  Flushing after every line gave me the desired "slow release" of the contents of a file. :-)